# When sharing a Windows 10 photo album, recipient cannot open the album

Tags: windows-10, photos, sharing

I am using Windows 10 Education version 1909. I have created an album using Microsoft Photos 2020.19111.24110.0. I uploaded it to OneDrive and generate a link using Share/Copy a link. When I emailed the link the recipient was asked to log into their OneDrive account.

How can I create an album to share that does not require the recipient to be logged into/have OneDrive? The folder is not visible in my OneDrive folders.

Comment: To do what you want, the recipient must log into One Drive. If that is not practical, you need to use a different sharing mechanism. All sharing mechanisms I know require sign on

Comment: Thanks. I only want read-only or download access - does sign in apply to that as well

Comment: Maybe look at Drop Box or Box and see if they fit your needs